# Android: MediaStore query for jpeg fails

Tags: android, mediastore

My MediaStore query for "image/jpeg" started failing a few weeks ago, presumably coinciding with an Android version update.

Here's my code:

```
final String[] projection = {
  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, // 0
  MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,  // 1
  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, // 2
};
final String selection = "MIME_TYPE = \"image/jpeg\"";
final String[] selectionArgs = null;
String order = MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
logD ("ID getMediaFiles: query");
final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver ().query (
  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  projection,
  selection,
  selectionArgs,
  order);
```

It throws an IllegalArgumentException with the message "Invalid token image/jpeg".

I'm running Android 11 (that's all the detail my phone reports), which presumably is API 30.

Comment: Try `MIME_TYPE=?` and putting `image/jpeg` in `selectionArgs`.

Comment: What should the sort order be?

Comment: CommonsWare - good idea. I think it should work as I wrote it, but that might be a good workaround.

Comment: By the way, it worked. Thanks.